# Is there a pendant to activerecord in playframework

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, playframework

is there something similiar in playframework like the aciverecord from ruby on rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box instantiation of active record design pattern in Playframework.

However, if you're using Play! with Scala, you can have a look to scala-activerecord which is an ORM library for Scala (https://github.com/aselab/scala-activerecord)

If you are using, Slick 3.x, you can try ActiveSlick (http://www.strongtyped.io/active-slick/). A good way is to start with the activator template http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/slick-active-record

Comment: Thanks wanna Use Java. Thought about Slick.

Comment: What other good practises are available for persisting Data?